# Click button when it changes to Active

Tags: javascript, html, web

Im currently trying to find a solution for my problem, I have a website were orders come in and there is a button which turns blue and I need to click it to accept all orders.

The logic behind it, it's a button which stays grey all the time, when a order enters it turns blue and active, and needs to be pressed. It's website in the browser.

```
window.onload=function() {

  setInterval(autoClick,100);
}

function autoClick() {

  if(document.getElementsByClassName("accept").length>0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("accept")[0].click();
  }
}
```

I've started this but don't know how it shoud detect if the button turns blue.

Comment: does this button have some id or other selector you can use to query for it?

Comment: Yeah it has an ID its "acceptorders"

Comment: How do you manage your state?

Comment: 1)how many buttons with an accept class are present? 2)can their number change dynamically? 3)how do they get blue?

Comment: There is only one single button in the website, the button changes dynamically without any refresh. When an orders enters it turns blue.

Comment: A class is added to the button which turns the button blue, and "clickable"

Comment: its "neworder" which makes it blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is query for the id of this exact button and get its `classList`

Then you check if the `classLsit` contains the class you are looking for.

It would look something like this.

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
console.log(btn.classList.contains("basic")); // true or false
```

Answer (score 1):

so your code must be

```
window.onload=function()
  {
  const myAcceptButton = document.querySelector('.accept')

  setInterval(autoClick,100);

  function autoClick()
    {
    if (myAcceptButton.classList.contains('neworder'))
      {
      myAcceptButton.click();
      }
    }
  }
```

or shorter code with arrow function

```
window.onload=function() {

  const myAcceptButton = document.querySelector('.accept')

  setInterval(() => {
    if (myAcceptButton.classList.contains('neworder'))
      { myAcceptButton.click(); }
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Do i need to loop the script or does it check all the time if a class has been added

Comment: @AdamD. setInterval takes care of doing this loop on its own, but 100 milliseconds seems very close to me